# Delete current row in a <table> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that lists a bunch of customers. The last cell is an ajax delete button.

I want the row containing the deleted customer to be deleted through jQuery.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Customer info 1</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(1);">Delete</a></td>
<tr><td>Customer info 2</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(2);">Delete</a></td>
```

```
function deleteCustomer(customerId)
{
$.post("somepage.php", {cid:customerId}, function(data){
//...delete the row that called the function...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting is very relative...

All you really want is the user to not see it anymore. If you select the entire row, you can call toggle() on it, to make it hidden to the user. On the next page load it won't be there anyway (assuming your ajax request deleted it alright), so as long as it is hidden, it is as good as deleted...

Many ways to get back to the row. You can give it a unique ID of customerRow + the id.. so you have rows..

```
<tr id="customerRow1"> ... </tr>
<tr id="customerRow2"> ... </tr>
```

Then just call toggle on the element with the id customerRow + customerId

```
$("#customerRow" + customerId).toggle()
```

You could also add this as a parameter:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Customer info 1</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(1,this);">Delete</a></td>
<tr><td>Customer info 2</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(2,this);">Delete</a></td>
```

Your function would become:

```
function deleteCustomer(customerId,element) {
    $.post("somepage.php", {cid:customerId}, function(data){
        $(element).closest("tr").toggle()
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, but then my question is how do i select the row that called the function?

Answer (score 2):

You could add **this** as a parameter:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Customer info 1</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(1,this);">Delete</a></td>
<tr><td>Customer info 2</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(2,this);">Delete</a></td>
```

Your function would become:

```
function deleteCustomer(customerId,element) {
    $.post("somepage.php", {cid:customerId}, function(data){
        $(element).closest("tr").remove();
    });
}
```

Another approach is to assign an id to each row:

```
<table>
<tr id='row_1'><td>Customer info 1</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(1);">Delete</a></td>
<tr id='row_2'><td>Customer info 2</td><td><a href="javascript:deleteCustomer(2);">Delete</a></td>
```

Then you delete the row like this:

```
$("tr[id=row_" + customerId + "]").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written an article on the same topic, you can check it out here:

**[Deleting Table Rows Using JQuery and PHP](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/deleting-table-rows-using-jquery-and-php/)**